# table-valued parameter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to create table-valued parameter to pass for stored procedure for the following table.

**Example**:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE tabletype
(
ID int identity(1,1) not null,
cola varchar(10) null
);
```

Creating table valued parameter:

```
CREATE TYPE tt as table( cola varchar(10));
```

Creating Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROC sptabletype
@tabtype tt readonly 

AS

INSERT INTO tabletype
select * from @tabtype
EXCEPT
select * from tabletype

select @@ROWCOUNT

GO
```

**Note**: Getting error while creating stored procedure.

**Error**:

```
All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator 
must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `tabletype` has 2 columns and your type `tt` has only 1. As the error suggests, yuo need to have the same number of columns returned by both parts of the query. I suspect what you want to do is:

```
select cola from @tabtype
EXCEPT
select cola from tabletype
```

Comment: Yeah! I got it. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your tables does not match. As the error says, please put like the below

```
select cola from @tabtype
EXCEPT
select cola from tabletype
```